# How to add feature to auxiliary layer and commit changes to auxilliary field in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis-3

I can't figure how to do that, here is my code :

```
auxKeyField = myLayer.fields().field(myLayer.fields().indexOf('id'))
auxStorage = QgsProject.instance().auxiliaryStorage()
myAuxLayer = auxStorage.createAuxiliaryLayer(auxKeyField, myLayer)
myLayer.setAuxiliaryLayer(myAuxLayer)

propAux = QgsPropertyDefinition()
propAux.setName('auxfield')
propAux.setDataType(QgsPropertyDefinition.DataTypeNumeric)
res = myAuxLayer.addAuxiliaryField(propAux)
auxLayerFields = myAuxLayer.fields()

auxFeature = QgsVectorLayerUtils.createFeature(myAuxLayer)
auxFeature.setAttribute('ASPK', 1)
auxFeature.setAttribute('_auxfield', 123)
res = myAuxLayer.addFeature(auxFeature)

myAuxLayer.save()
```

Auxiliary field is created, addFeature returns true, the auxiliary field column appears in attribute table, but it contains only NULL values, even for id=1.

EDIT 1 : Adding `myLayer.startEditing()` at the beginning of the code, adding `myLayer.commitChanges()` at the end, and removing `myAuxLayer.save()` seemed to solve the problem. Unfortunately, as soon as I save the project, every value in the auxiliary field disappears...

EDIT 2 : Looking at [unit tests](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsauxiliarystorage.py) I ended up with this code :

```
auxKeyField = myLayer.fields().field(myLayer.fields().indexOf('id'))
auxStorage = QgsProject.instance().auxiliaryStorage()
myAuxLayer = auxStorage.createAuxiliaryLayer(auxKeyField, myLayer)
myLayer.setAuxiliaryLayer(myAuxLayer)

propAux = QgsPropertyDefinition(
    'offset',  # name
    'string',  # description
    QgsPropertyDefinition.Offset,  # type
    'symbol',  # origin
    'decalop'  # comment
)
res = myAuxLayer.addAuxiliaryField(propAux)

req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('id=1')
myFeature = QgsFeature()
myLayer.getFeatures(req).nextFeature(myFeature )
auxFieldName = QgsAuxiliaryLayer.nameFromProperty(propAux, True)
index = myLayer.fields().indexOf(auxFieldName)
myLayer.changeAttributeValue(myFeature.id(), index, 123)
```

Sadly, every value in the auxiliary field still disappear as soon as I save the project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it didn't work because myLayer was a virtual layer, referencing a WFS source. Changing it to a straight WFS layer made it work like a charm, with second version of code (EDIT 2)...